# Matrix by Reference - C

Tags: c

I'm trying to receive a matrix by reference and add the elements to another complementary matrix. That is, my method will receive 3 arguments: a matrix, a line and a column.

I must not take the line and column received when I fill the new matrix.
Well, I'm having trouble with this method:

```
int **matrizComplementar(int **matOriginal, int linha, int coluna){

    int y = 0;
    int k = 0;  
    // Aloca espaço para matriz complementar
    int ** matCompl = retornarMatrizQuadrada(N-1);

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        if(i != linha){
            for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
                if(j != coluna)
                {
                    matCompl[y][k] = matOriginal[i][j]; <<< When i read or write
                                                          I get "Sigment Default"
                    k++;
                }
            }
            y++;
        }
        k = 0;      
    }   
    return matCompl;
}
```

The whole code is below.

```
int ** preecherMatriz(int ** mat){

    // Preenche a matriz inicial
    for( int k = 0; k < N; k++ ){
        for( int l = 0; l < N; l++ ){
            printf("Entre com o Valor [%d][%d]: ", k ,l );
            scanf("%d", &mat[k][l]);
        }
    }
}

int ** retornarMatrizQuadrada(int tamN){

    // Aloca matriz de tamanho N
    int ** mat;
    mat = (int **)malloc((tamN)*sizeof(int*));
    for (int i=0; i<tamN; i++)
        mat[i] = (int *)malloc((tamN)*sizeof(int));

    return mat;
}

void imprimirMatriz(int ** m){

    // Mostra ao usuário
    printf("\nMatriz complementar:\n");
    for( int k = 0; k < N-1; k++ ){
        for( int l = 0; l < N-1; l++ )
        printf("%d ", &m[k][l]);
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    }
}

int ** matrizComplementar(int **matOriginal, int linha, int coluna){

    int y = 0;
    int k = 0;  
    // Aloca espaço para matriz complementar
    int ** matCompl = retornarMatrizQuadrada(N-1);

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        if(i != linha){
            for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
                if(j != coluna)
                {
                    matCompl[y][k] = matOriginal[i][j];
                    k++;
                }
            }
            y++;
        }
        k = 0;      
    }   
    return matCompl;
}

int main(void) {    
    imprimirMatriz(matrizComplementar(preecherMatriz(retornarMatrizQuadrada(N)), 1,2)); 
}
```

Comment: Am I right in understanding that given a square matrix NxN, you want the `matrizComplementar()` function to return a square (N-1)x(N-1) matrix which is a copy of the bigger matrix except that the specified row (line) and column have been left out?  I don't see a definition of N.  It would probably be better to pass N as a parameter to the functions — maybe even using VLA (variable length array) notations.  You don't check any memory allocations.  Your matrix printing code needs some curly brackets and a newline at the end of each row.

Comment: "Am I right in understanding that given a square matrix NxN, you want the matrizComplementar() function to return a square (N-1)x(N-1) matrix which is a copy of the bigger matrix except that the specified row (line) and column have been left out? "
- You're right. 

" I don't see a definition of N"

 - N is an integer that is define area. I've forgotten to add those lines.

Comment: "You don't check any memory allocations."

- This method allocate memory for any matrix N, and this N is received by parameter and returns a pointer.

int ** retornarMatrizQuadrada(int tamN){

    // Aloca matriz de tamanho N
    int ** mat;
    mat = (int **)malloc((tamN)*sizeof(int*));
    for (int i=0; i<tamN; i++)
        mat[i] = (int *)malloc((tamN)*sizeof(int));

    return mat;
}

Comment: "Your matrix printing code needs some curly brackets and a newline at the end of each row"

- This is the printin' method.

void imprimirMatriz(int ** m){

    // Mostra ao usuário
    printf("\nMatriz complementar:\n");
    for( int k = 0; k < N-1; k++ ){
        for( int l = 0; l < N-1; l++ )
        printf("%d ", &m[k][l]);
    printf("\n");  <<< Here a go to the next row.
    system("pause");
    }
}

Comment: My compiler tells me that you don't return a value from `preecherMatriz()`, which is sad because you use that value when you call `matrizComplementar()` — it's probably why your program crashes. Your 4 function calls in a single line are scary. I'd not write code like that, especially where memory allocation is involved. Your `printf()` also prints the address of the array element (incorrectly): you should drop the `&`.  (One reason for not liking the multiple function calls — you don't keep track of the allocated memory, so you can't free it. It may not matter here; it does in most programs.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237678/matrix-by-reference-c?noredirect=1#comment89514768_51237678):

> My compiler tells me that you don't return a value from `preecherMatriz()`, which is sad because you use that value when you call `matrizComplementar()` — it's probably why your program crashes. Your 4 function calls in a single line are scary. I'd not write code like that, especially where memory allocation is involved. Your `printf()` also prints the address of the array element (incorrectly): you should drop the `&`.
>
> One reason for not liking the multiple function calls — you don't keep track of the allocated memory, so you can't free it. It may not matter here; it does in most programs.

Here's an MCVE based closely on your code, that runs without crashing and produces the result I expect:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 5

static int **preecherMatriz(int **mat)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < N; l++)
        {
            printf("Entre com o Valor [%d][%d]: ", k, l);
            scanf("%d", &mat[k][l]);
        }
    }
    return mat;
}

static int **retornarMatrizQuadrada(int tamN)
{
    int **mat;
    mat = (int **)malloc((tamN) * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < tamN; i++)
        mat[i] = (int *)malloc((tamN) * sizeof(int));
    return mat;
}

static void imprimirMatriz(int **m)
{
    printf("\nMatriz complementar:\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < N - 1; k++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < N - 1; l++)
            printf(" %3d", m[k][l]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

static int **matrizComplementar(int **matOriginal, int linha, int coluna)
{
    int y = 0;
    int k = 0;

    int **matCompl = retornarMatrizQuadrada(N - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (i != linha)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                if (j != coluna)
                {
                    matCompl[y][k] = matOriginal[i][j];
                    k++;
                }
            }
            y++;
        }
        k = 0;
    }
    return matCompl;
}

int main(void)
{
    imprimirMatriz(matrizComplementar(preecherMatriz(retornarMatrizQuadrada(N)), 1, 2));
}
```

The only changes are to make the functions `static` (to get past my extremely fussy compiler options), plus the extra `return` and the removed `&`, and I removed `system("pause");` in the matrix printing function.  I've not added checking for memory allocation failures — it should be done, but I've not done it.

Sample output (program name `mtx29`):

```
$ mtx29
Entre com o Valor [0][0]: 100
Entre com o Valor [0][1]: 101
Entre com o Valor [0][2]: 102
Entre com o Valor [0][3]: 103
Entre com o Valor [0][4]: 104
Entre com o Valor [1][0]: 210
Entre com o Valor [1][1]: 211
Entre com o Valor [1][2]: 212
Entre com o Valor [1][3]: 213
Entre com o Valor [1][4]: 214
Entre com o Valor [2][0]: 320
Entre com o Valor [2][1]: 321
Entre com o Valor [2][2]: 322
Entre com o Valor [2][3]: 323
Entre com o Valor [2][4]: 324
Entre com o Valor [3][0]: 498
Entre com o Valor [3][1]: 497
Entre com o Valor [3][2]: 476
Entre com o Valor [3][3]: 465
Entre com o Valor [3][4]: 454
Entre com o Valor [4][0]: 511
Entre com o Valor [4][1]: 522
Entre com o Valor [4][2]: 533
Entre com o Valor [4][3]: 544
Entre com o Valor [4][4]: 555

Matriz complementar:
 100 101 103 104
 320 321 323 324
 498 497 465 454
 511 522 544 555
$
```

So, your code was close to working, but either you were ignoring compiler warnings (don't!) or your compiler wasn't giving you all the help you need — find out how to turn up the warning level.

The code shown (`mtx29.c`) compiles cleanly on a Mac running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 using GCC 8.1.0, and the command line:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     mtx29.c -o mtx29
$
```

Comment: Man, sensational !  I really enjoyed all the analysis and explanation u gave. I understand perfectly. I will modify here as you have guided and test.
   Thanks bro!

Comment: Jonathan, it worked perfectly in Dev C ++ Windows too.
Note: I qualified your answer just as the FAC teaches.
Thanks.